# How can I concatenate a list

Tags: c#

I need to concatenate these values, I've seen examples using string builder but I cant quite figure it.

I am trying to return recreate the linestrings of https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/140/Route/Sequence/Inbound

However the results I have to return, have more than 1 string of co-ords hence the adding "[", "]"

//

```
for (int i = 0; i < R.geometry.coordinates.Count; i++)

    foreach (List<List<double>> C in R.geometry.coordinates)

    {

        RS.lineStrings.Add(i++.ToString());
        RS.lineStrings.Add("[");
        foreach (List<double> a in C)
        {   
       // These values are to be concatentated, I'm wanting to create a string of RS.lineStrings.Add($"[{a[1]},{a[0]}]");
            RS.lineStrings.Add($"[{a[1]},{a[0]}]");  
        }

        RS.lineStrings.Add("]");
        RS.lineStrings.Add(",");
}
```

Comment: What didn't you understand about the examples that you saw?  What confused you?  What didn't work when you tried using them in your situation?

Comment: Do you have list in list? What type is `C` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "concatenate"? Just stick them together, or add some separator (space, comma, end-of-line) between them?

Comment: You seem to confuse concatenating lists and concatenating strings. What exactly do you want to concatenate? Should the result be a string or a list?

Comment: In general, if you are working with an arbitrary collection of stuff and you want to concatenate them into a string, you shouldn't be using string concatenation.  It's much slower and it generates a lot of _garbage_ that needs to be _garbage collected_.  StringBuilder is _**much**_ better at this.  Just juse `StringBuilder.Append` and convert the result to a string with `ToString` at the end.

Comment: RS.lineStrings.Add(string.concat("[{a[1]}","{a[0]}]");

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes While not actually a List or Array, string does has functions like "Add" and even indexers. So mistaking it for a array is quite possible.

Comment: you want to join first items together, then second items, ...?

Comment: you want something like: `[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]`?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but what ever you are trying to do seems wrong. Why would you need to add those into your list? `RS.lineStrings.Add("," or i++.ToString() or "[" or "]");`

Comment: You already have five answers. Why don't you take one and run with it?

Comment: @mac001 - you not supposed to add your answers to other people posts. If you want to post new information, either add a comment or add to your question. If this is an answer - add a full answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering in your code `C` is `List<List<double>>`. Then you can use LINQ to **concatenate**

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(C.Count * 20); // appox length not to resize

C.ForEach(item => sb.AppendFormat("[{0},{1}]", item[1], item[0]));

var str = sb.ToString(); // This is concatenation.
```

If you want **list** of strings

```
C.Select(item => $"[{item[1]},{item[0]}]").ToList();
```

Based on your new update (*I am trying to return "[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]"*) do this

```
var result = "[" + string.Join(",", C.Select(item => $"[{item[1]},{item[0]}]")) + "]";
```

Which method you choose - should depend on the details of your list. you can still do it with string builder for better memory management

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(C.Count * 20); // appox length not to resize

C.ForEach(item => sb.AppendFormat("[{0},{1}],", item[1], item[0])); // note comma - ],
sb.Insert(0, "[").Replace(',', ']', sb.Length - 1, 1); // this removes last comma, ads closing bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Join()` to join them:

```
string result = string.Join(",", C);
```

Comment: Misses the `[x]`

Comment: `foreach (List<double> a in C)` seems OP has nested list.

Comment: actually i now see that question is not that clear, so i'm waiting for an edit on question by OP

Answer (score 0):

Strings are inmutable. So if you do a lot of string connaction, that can leave a lot of dead strings in memory. The GC will deal with them, but it is still a performance issue. Especially on a Webserver it should be avoided. And then there are things like StringInterning too. A lot of minor optimisations that will get in the way if you do mass operations on strings.

[StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2#the-string-and-stringbuilder-types) is the closest we can get to a mutable string, that get's around those optimsiations (wich may be a hinderance here). The only use difference is that you use "Append" rather then "Add".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities :

```
 RS.lineStrings.Add(string.concat("[{a[1]}" + "," + "{a[0]}]");
 RS.lineStrings.Add(string.concat("[{a[1]}",",","{a[0]}]");
```

Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a `StringBuilder`.  It's wordy as all get out, but it should be much faster and produce much less garbage for a large number of items.  It uses no string concatenation.

```
 var listOfLists = new List<List<double>>
 {
     new List<double> {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
     new List<double> {3.14, 42.0}
 };
 var buffer = new StringBuilder();
 buffer.Append('[');
 var firstOuter = true;
 foreach (var list in listOfLists)
 {
     var firstInner = true;
     buffer.Append('[');
     if (!firstOuter)
     {
         buffer.Append(',');
     }
     foreach (var item in list)
     {
         if (!firstInner)
         {
             buffer.Append(',');
         }

         firstInner = firstOuter = false;
         buffer.Append(item.ToString());
     }
     buffer.Append(']');
 }
 buffer.Append(']');

 var concatenated = buffer.ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah.  And, it gets worse after his update.  Deleting this

Comment: I updated this to match the format that his question now shows - it makes things worse.  However, if the number of items in his collections is large, string concatenation is a bad idea (it's slow and _garbage_ producing).  If it's small, who cares.

Comment: yes. But since these people are stingy on telling details, we can be generous and show all the ways to do this simple operation